# How to pass class using Dependency Injection that accept DbContext as a parameter in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

**I have class UnitOFWork that accept Context class as parameter, so how can i pass this class using Dependency Injection**

This are my classes

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    public Context context;

    public UnitOfWork(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}

 public class Context : DbContext
 {
     public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
     {
     }
 }
```

so how to pass the instance of unitofwork class using dependency injection.
Thank You!

Comment: You register the services with the DI framework in your startup code, like `services.AddScoped<UnitOfWork>()`? You generally don't want to add a unit of work layer around Entity Framework, as it is one of itself already.

Comment: @CodeCaster: The eternal argue :P Generally I would agree with you, if DbContext was UnitTestable, but it isn't. That's the reason why 99% of the people abstract it away

Comment: [This is the first hit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ConfigureServices method (generally in Startup or Program depending on your project), define the service.

```
services.AddScoped<Context>();
services.AddScoped<UnitOfWork>();
```

When constructing a class that asks for a parameter of type `UnitOfWork`, the Dependency Injector will construct `UnitOfWork` - and to do that it will also construct `Context`. The newly created `UnitOfWork` instance will be passed into the next class down the line.

```
public class DoesWork
{
    UnitOfWork _unit;
    public DoesWork(UnitOfWork unit)
    {
        _unit = unit;
    }
    public void Work()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A non-null unit was passed in: {0}.", _unit != null);
    }
}
```

Generally to get a class that actually does something, you'll want to use a method like the following in your Startup/Program file: `services.AddHostedService<UnitOfWorkWorkerService>()`.
`services.AddControllersWithViews()` in ASP.Net Core will do a similar thing for all of your Controller classes.
And have a class somewhere that may use your DI-generated classes. The worker service class will be constructed in Main(), in CreateHostBuilder().

```
public class UnitOfWorkWorkerService : BackgroundService
{
    public UnitOfWorkWorkerService(DoesWork fromDependencyInjection)
    {
        _doesWork = fromDependencyInjection;
    }
    private readonly DoesWork _doesWork;
    // This method will be called when your application is started.
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _doesWork.Work();
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that these examples are derived from a Hosted Service application that I have, which are similar conceptually but simpler than ASP.Net Core applications, etc.